# Как получить переданные данные с клиента на сервер?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Получаю текст книги с клиента, который хочу хранить в базе данных:

```js
profileDownWritingForm.addEventListener('submit', () => {
        const file = document.querySelector('.profile__down-writing-form-book').files[0];
        const reader = new FileReader();
    
        reader.readAsText(file);
    
        reader.onload = function() {
            const textBook = reader.result;
            const URL = window.location.href.split('/');
            const ID = URL[URL.length-1];

            fetch(`/profile/${ID}/book`, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(textBook)
            })
        }
    
        reader.onerror = function() {
            console.log(reader.error);
        }
    })
```

Как получить этот текст на сервере?

```js
router.post('/profile/:id/book', async(req, res) => {
    try {
        // code
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала Вам нужно установить

```
$ npm install --save body-parser
```

прослушать мидлеваре `bodyParser`

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser);
```

а затем уже

```
router.post('/profile/:id/book', async(req, res) => {
    try {
       console.dir(req.body);
       //code
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
})
```